# Java Swing GlassPane Drag Performance

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, glasspane

I'm trying to do a visual drag and drop in my Swing application using a GlassPane, but am running into the problem that the drag image lags behind the mouse pointer, sometimes considerably. How do I solve this? My GlassPane code is below. Thanks!

```
package dragui;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.event.MouseInputAdapter;

public class GlassPane extends JComponent {
    private int x=0, y=0, k=25,z=1;
    private boolean showDot;
    private MouseInputAdapter mia = new MouseInputAdapter(){

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
            setPos(me.getX(), me.getY());
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
            setShow(true);
            setPos(me.getX(), me.getY());   
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me){
            setShow(false);
            setVisible(false);
        }
    };

    public void setShow(boolean b){ this.showDot = b; }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        if (showDot) {
            g.setColor(new Color(0.0f, 0.25f, 1.0f));
            g.fillOval(x - k, y - k, 2*k, 2*k);
        }
    }

    public void setPos(int x, int y) {
        int tmpX = this.x, tmpY = this.y; 
        this.x = x; this.y = y;
        repaint(tmpX - k , tmpY-k, 2*k+5, 2*k+5);
        repaint(this.x-k, this.y-k, 2*k+5, 2*k+5);        
    }

    public GlassPane() {
        addMouseListener(mia); 
        addMouseMotionListener(mia);
        setOpaque(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to override `paint(...)`? Shouldn't you be overriding `paintComponent(...)`? `paint(...)` will paint the component's contents, borders, and children.

Comment: What do you mean with _sometimes considerably_. I dont get the cursor out of the circle

Comment: @mre I don't think it makes a difference performance wise, as my paint isn't doing all of those things and doesn't call super.paint

Comment: @oliholz if I just hold down the mouse button and move the mouse around, I'll see things like the dot freezing for a second every so often, or the cursor being outside (in "front" of) the dot for a while. Also, I've got some controls on the contentPane below the GlassPane: a SplitPane containing a scrolling JList with ~20 items (rendered as JPanels containing 3 JLabels by a custom ListCellRenderer) and a JLayeredPane with some JLabels displaying images -- so that'd be a difference from your example, since there's redrawing involved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paint%28java.awt.Graphics%29),

> A subclass that just wants to
>   specialize the UI (look and feel)
>   delegate's paint method should just
>   override paintComponent.

And this is because `paint(...)` actually delegates the work of painting to three protected methods: `paintComponent`, `paintBorder`, and `paintChildren`. That being said, try replacing `paint(...)` with this

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    if (showDot) {
        Graphics gCopy = g.create();

        gCopy.setColor(new Color(0.0f, 0.25f, 1.0f));
        gCopy.fillOval(x - k, y - k, 2*k, 2*k);

        gCopy.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: @mKorbel, Are you sure he's talking about an _actual_ [Glass Pane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html), or about his GlassPane custom component?

Comment: @mre hmmmm that's the question, in other hand you said good reason why its doesn't works

Comment: @mre hmmm I checked example from this tutorial and looks like as you are right, GlassPane and RootPane could be extended with JComponents, then paintComponent() is correct, agreed good to know +1

Comment: @mre Why are you instantiating gCopy?

Comment: @mre Also, what do you mean by an "actual Glass Pane"? My understanding of the Root Pane examples was that you *must* designate your own component using setGlassPane?

Comment: @Frobba Bobba, With regard to your first question, this technique avoids clobbering the state of the original graphics object. With regard to your second question, see @mKorbel's comment(s).

Comment: @Frobba Bobba, Then your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @mre Any suggestions as to diagnosing where? I'm at my wits end

Comment: @Frobba Bobba, your double invocation of `repaint(...)` in `setPos(...)` is interesting...

Comment: @mre As far as I know, I have to do that, so that I erase the previous dot draw the new one, but Swing collapses those calls into a single operation

Comment: @Frobba Bobba, are you sure Swing collapses those calls into a single operation? I know the `EDT` will do that with other (albeit same) events, but I'm not sure if this applies to invoking repaint, especially with two distinct calls to repaint

Comment: @mre " the asynchronous repaint() will cause multiple overlapping requests to be collapsed efficiently" --http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/#paint_process

Comment: @mre That same article mentions paintImmediately, which I'm going to try now

Comment: @Frobba Bobba, thanks for the link to the article! I suppose it's just a little confusing to me because they're referencing repaint without any parameters...I wasn't sure if repaint with parameters was treated any differently, which I thought it would be since I can't imagine collapsing them would result in the desired paint job...

Comment: @mre, I think it gives the desired paint since you'd call repaint with parameters describing various rectangles of the screen you want updated, and then that would get collapsed into a single "unioned" rectangle which would have its area repainted?

Comment: @Frobba Bobba, you would think so, right? but that's a lot of assuming. why not just invoke repaint once and explicitly pass the entire affected area? -- couldn't hurt! :)

Comment: @Frobba Bobba, report back please! I apologize for not having the answer readily available :/

Comment: testing it now, will report in a minute or so

Comment: @Frobba Bobba, my pleasure! thanks for being so responsive -- it shows that you care, and that's what counts. :)

Comment: @mre I will vote this as the correct answer though, as it's been a very useful discussion. Thanks again!

Comment: @Frobba Bobba, that's too bad! I wish I could help you out some more. If you have the time, perhaps upload some more code (provide a link to source, if you want) and I can play around with it if you haven't figured out what's truly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you should not creating a `new Color(0.0f, 0.25f, 1.0f)` on every repaint.

For me the performance is quiet nice.

```
public class Example {
    static public void main( String[] s ) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setBounds( 50, 50, 600, 600 );
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
                frame.setGlassPane( new JComponent() {
                    {
                        MouseInputAdapter mia = new MouseInputAdapter(){
                            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
                                setPos(me.getX(), me.getY());
                            }
                            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
                                setShow(true);
                                setPos(me.getX(), me.getY());   
                            }
                            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me){
                                setShow(false);
                                setVisible(false);
                            }
                        };
                        addMouseListener(mia); 
                        addMouseMotionListener(mia);
                        setOpaque(false);
                    }
                    private int x=0, y=0, k=25,z=1;
                    private boolean showDot;
                    public void setShow(boolean b){ this.showDot = b; }
                    private Color color = new Color(0.0f, 0.25f, 1.0f);
                    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                        if (showDot) {
                            g.setColor(color);
                            g.fillOval(x - k, y - k, 2*k, 2*k);
                        }
                    }
                    public void setPos(int x, int y) {
                        int tmpX = this.x, tmpY = this.y; 
                        this.x = x; this.y = y;
                        repaint(tmpX - k , tmpY-k, 2*k+5, 2*k+5);
                        repaint(this.x-k, this.y-k, 2*k+5, 2*k+5);        
                    }
                } );
                frame.getGlassPane().setVisible( true );
                frame.setVisible( true );
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: And yeah, notice that you're overriding `paintComponent(...)` instead -- you're welcome.